# Edit blog post on Django but not make it visible until finished

Tags: django, django-admin

The question is basically in title. I was wondering if there is a way for a user to edit a blog post in Django admin but not make it visible to the public until finalized?

Comment: just make it invisible after the edition, you can use a pre_save signal in this case.

Comment: Thank you but I don't know what a pre_save signal is or how to make it invisible? Can you elaborate?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/signals/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If the blog post hasn't been published yet**

you can add a boolean field to the model, eg,

```
published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And only display the post if published is True. Another option would be to set a publication_date field and only display if today's date is greater than that.

**If the post is already published,**

That gets a little more complicated. You'll need to be able to save the changes without disturbing the existing post until the changes are finalised.

To do that you could use two separate fields, one for content and one for editable_content, and another field to indicate whether you want to update from editable_content or not. In your public facing app you, of course, only show content, but admin will be able to see all fields. Something like:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(...)
    editable_content = models.TextField(...)
    sync_editable = models.BooleanField(
         default=False, 
         help_text = "Click to update content from editable_content")
    
    def save(self):
        #check if you want to update from edited version
        if sync_editable:
             self.content = self.editable_content
             #reset sync_editable to prevent accidents
             self.sync_editable = False
        elif self.editable_content = "":
             #keep things in sync for easier editing later
             self.editable_content = self.content
        super().save()
```